# Putting a recessed light in over the shower unit

Tags: bathroom, shower, light

There is 1 ordinary light in the bathroom. ( old house ) im going to change this to a ledlight, then i am going to wire from this light to put an IP65 recessed light over the shower unit. Is it ok to wire it from the centre light ? Or do i need to wire it from the switch ? Would i need to change the wiring in bathroom for this ?

Comment: Where is this? Differently countries and even different jurisdictions within a country have different regulations. But as far as what works, you can just wire the shower enclosure light to the existing one which, I assume, is controlled by a wall switch. In new construction one might have separate switches, but for a retrofit I doubt it would be worth the trouble.

Comment: Thanks jim, ireland is the country. Thats all i wanted to hear 

Comment: Paul, Jim has a tendency to put answers in comments and then post proper answers later. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand what you're expected to do to resolve this question once he does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different countries and even different jurisdictions within a country have different regulations. You should find out what is allowed inside a shower enclosure. One thing that comes to mind is whether this fixture must be GFCI protected ([RCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device)). It could be that in Ireland RCD is present in the master breaker.

But as far as what works, you can just wire the shower enclosure light to the existing one which, I assume, is controlled by a wall switch. In new construction one might have separate switches, but for a retrofit I doubt it would be worth the trouble.